# Wordpress redirects to local ip adress when trying to login

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, nginx, networking

I have a LEMP server on a ubuntu machine, on which I have installed wordpress.org. After that, I port forwarded 192.168.1.86 from the router to my public ip adress with TCP port as 80. So when I type in my ip adress, it opens up the wordpress website which works fine. However, whenever I try to login, it redirects me back to 192.168 (Local IP) instead of the public one.

Here is the website- http://182.68.215.7

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not able to open the website address but I think you need to change the address in 'wp_options' table of your wordpress site database to your new address.

Comment: Is there a documentation I can follow for this? I'm quite new to wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

From searching around around, I found out that the fix was literally right infront of me but I didn't do any exploration.
I just had to change the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) present in Wordpress Settings > General.